# onchanging orientation popup not set to according my CSS

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova

I am working on Cordova 3.1.0 And Android 17.

my html code for pop

```
   <div id="rightNavPrpPopup1" data-role="popup" class="r-menu-dropdown">
        <div class="r-menu-triangle" ></div>
        <a class="class-a" data-transition="slide">A</a>
        <a class="class-b" data-transition="slide">B</a>
        <a class="class-c" data-transition="slide">C</a>
        <a class="class-d" data-transition="slide">D</a>

    </div>
```

and my CSS is

```
.r-menu-dropdown{
 margin: 30px 5px 0 0;
 border-bottom: none;
}
.r-menu-dropdown a{
padding: 10px;
display: block;
color: #fff !important;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
background: #555;
}
.r-menu-dropdown a:hover, .r-main-menu-dropdown a:hover{
 background: #444;
 }
 .r-menu-triangle{
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0 7.5px 13px 7.5px;
 border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent;
 position: absolute;
 right: -1px;
 top: -14px;
 }
```

And my problem is that when my orientation is change then my pop is not set according to css Pop is going to center(on both mode). if i didnot change my orientation then my pop is coming properly. On the flying time of popup if I change my orientation then it is going to center and never come back to my privious position even i swap the orientation.
[image]

How can I resolve this issuue please help me? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify absolute or fixed position for `.r-menu-dropdown`

```
.r-menu-dropdown{
     position:fixed;
     right : 30px; // change according to your requirement
     top : 40px;
     border-bottom: none;
}
```

choice between fixed or absolute depends on if you want the popup to scroll with rest of the content or not.

Comment: No change Same issue.

Comment: do you have any parents of `.r-menu-dropdown` which have `position` property set in CSS?

Comment: alternatively, you can try JS: attach `window.onresize` listener and change style accordingly.

Comment: yes tried window.onresize.   and also i tried to close and reopen my pop on orientation change nothing will going to work.

Comment: It seems you have a parent element of `.r-menu-dropdown` which has relative or absolute position in its CSS. try removing that, or keep `.r-menu-dropdown` out of that parent.

Comment: no their is only Jquery mobile header. inside this header i have .r-menu-dropdown

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40611/discussion-between-shailendr-singh-and-pranav-gupta)

Answer (score 0):

Call any repaint in browser. In your css code there is nobody to repaint for browser when orientation is changed.

Try to add style:

`html, body {`

`width: 100%;`

`min-width: 100%;`

`height: 100%;`

`min-height: 100%;`

`}`

Comment: I this code  not work. I also tried with mediaquery but i didnot work.
On working on this issue realize may be dynamicall some is added some class for by Jquery mobile according to these class my pop is not coming.     for this i also tried with !important on particular css code. but nothing is going to work.

Comment: where did check it. on browser or in android Phone or Emulator.?

Comment: Where are checking your code On desktop browser or in Android device or in android Emulator.actually I check my code in real device and emulator.